# How to export a variable from a perl script into a shell script?

Tags: shell-script, environment-variables, perl, variable

I have a shell script in which I am running perl script by below code.

```
perl perlscript.pl
```

In the perl script I have defined a variable called `$circle`. Now I want to use this variable value in my shell script. How can I call?

Comment: Does your Perl script produce any other output to _stdout_?

Comment: You can use perl code to update your `PATH` and set an environment variable.

Comment: please provide more details.  e.g. sample output from your perlscript.pl and maybe the script itself (or a minimal versison of it).

Comment: Put your perl scritp into your post.

Comment: @Programmer400, you cannot. You can alter the variables *while the perl script is running* but once it exits, whatever it changed will exit along with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your `perl` script produces no other output than the value of $circle, you can use command substitution to store that output in a variable.  For example:

```
circle=$(perl perlscript.pl)
```

If the `perl` script produces other output as well (or not output at all), you'll have to either:

1. extract only the value you want from the output using the usual text processing tools (`sed`, `awk`, `perl`, `grep`, etc).  Here's a very simple example:

   `circle=$(perl perlscript.pl | sed -e 's/junk.i.dont.want//')`
2. use an indirect method, such as having the `perl` script write the value of $circle to a file (e.g. `/path/to/circle`) for your shell to read it (e.g. `circle=$(cat /path/to/circle)`)

NOTE: Without more details from you, it's impossible to provide more than generic advice like this.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the answer by @cas, here is an example where:

- The shell script creates a temp file to hold the variables
- Perl outputs the variables, which the shell script redirects to the temp file
- The shell sources the temp file (and deletes it)

If you don't use STDERR in your perl script, you can use that to redirect it to the temp file with `2>$tempfile`.

Here is a full example:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# create a temp file to hold the variables from perl
tmpfile=$(mktemp perlvars.XXXX)

#perl writes them to STDERR, which is redirected to the $tmpfile
perl -e '$var1="Perl Variable 1"; $var2="Other variable";
         print "In Perl: \$var1 = $var1, \$var2 = $var2\n";
         END { print STDERR qq(var1="$var1"\nvar2="$var2"\n) }' 2>$tmpfile

# source the $tmpfile and remove it
. "$tmpfile" && rm "$tmpfile"

echo "Now back in Bash: var1 = '$var1', var2 = '$var2'"
```

I you do also need STDERR in Perl, like if using `warn`or `die`, you can open another file descriptor in Perl with `open(F3, ">&=", 3)`, and write to that instead:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# create a temp file to hold the variables from perl
tmpfile=$(mktemp perlvars.XXXX)

#perl writes them to file handle 3, which is redirected to the $tmpfile
perl -e '$var1="Perl Variable 1"; $var2="Other variable";
         print "In Perl: \$var1 = $var1, \$var2 = $var2\n";
         END {open(F3, ">&=", 3);
              print F3 qq(var1="$var1"\nvar2="$var2"\n)}' 3>$tmpfile

# source the $tmpfile and remove it
. "$tmpfile" && rm "$tmpfile"

echo "Now back in Bash: var1 = '$var1', var2 = '$var2'"
```

Answer (score -3):

Just set an environment variable in perl and your shell will find it. In C you can check your path like this

```
void getPath() {
    if (getenv("PATH") == NULL) {
        printf("'%s' is not set.\n", "PATH");
        /* Default our path if it is not set. */
        putenv("PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/etc");
    }
    else if (getenv("PATH")) {
        printf("'%s' is set to %s.\n", "PATH", (getenv("PATH")));
    }
}
```

There are also functions for setting your path, so you can set an environment variable for your program in your code.

Comment: child processes (e.g. a perl script) can't change the parent's (e.g. the shell that the perl script was run from) environment.

Comment: @cas But you can have 2 shells at once can't I?

Comment: yes,  but a child process still can't change its parent's environment.  or the environment of an entirely unrelated process (e.g. a 2nd shell).  it **can** affect the environment of itself and any child processes it creates.